# VLC: Switching Audio Tracks Causes Sound to Go Silent for a Few Seconds

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player

When playing a video file with multiple audio tracks, I sometimes like to switch between the tracks while the video is playing. However, when I do so, there's a period of 2 - 3 seconds of silence before the new audio track kicks in. I'd like to transition between tracks seamlessly. Is there a way to do this in VLC?

Comment: It's likely the amount of buffering it's having to do. Switch the audio stream, it will take the buffer length to switch. I don't have the same issue here. idk how to adjust the buffer; it may be in the file caching section [I'm on Mac where the prefs are laid out totally differently to Win]

Comment: I'm actually on Linux. I thought audio buffering was controlled by VLC, not the OS.

Comment: I tried lowering the buffering via Settings -> Input/Codecs -> Advanced -> File caching, and that dramatically improved the audio issue. However, it also caused the video to lag and freeze. I don't suppose there's a way to have different caching times for the audio and video? Or, could I get VLC to cache all audio tracks (not just the one currently playing)?

Comment: Not that I know of. idk whether the buffers auto-adjust at first run or how else they may decide the defaults, but I imagine there's some kind of best guess going on. The video is going to need a lot more work than the audio, so it's probably based on video 'speed'. Other that 'get a faster computer' I have no clue how you'd work round this, sorry. The buffer is app-controlled, of course, it's just that the app & prefs interfaces on Mac are totally different to the ones on Win [idk nix]. They look like completely different apps, so finding a control on one doesn't mean it exists on the other.